# How to hide a specific element inside .map function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-rendering

I am looking for a way to hide a div once the button thats in it is clicked and continue to show all other div's.

I've tried using the setState method, however when setting it to false with onClick() all of my objects disappear.

```
class App extends React.PureComponent {

    state: {
        notHidden: false,       
    }

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {search: '', notHidden: true};

        this.hideObject = this.hideObject.bind(this)
    }

    hideThisDiv() {
        this.setState({notHidden: false})
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            objects: await api.getObjects()
        });
    }

render = (objects: Object[]) => {
return ({Object.map((object) => 

        <div key={index} className='class'>             
            <button className='hide' type='button' onClick={() => hideThisDiv()}>Hide</button>
            <p>object.text</p>
        </div>}

render() {  
        const {objects} = this.state;

        return (<main>
            <h1>Objects List</h1>
            <header>
                <input type="search" onChange={(e) => this.onSearch(e.target.value)}/>
            </header>
            {objects ? this.render(objects) : null}
        </main>)
    }
);
```

The data is a data.json file filled with many of these objects in the array

```
{
   "uuid": "dsfgkj24-sfg34-1r134ef"
   "text": "Some Text"
}
```

Edit: Sorry for the badly asked question, I am new to react.

Comment: Pleae provide more code, not just return. We would need to see your "object" and how u use useState

Comment: You will need to keep a state for ***all*** the mapped elements you want to "hide". You can then either conditionally render null if it should be hidden, or filter your state first then map. alternatively you can abstract the show/hide state into a a component that manages its own visibility. `() => hideThisDiv` isn't valid. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.

Comment: What's happening to this now. do we have the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, just a blueprint... is it what you want to do?
And yes I didn't hide, I removed but again, just an idea on how you can hide button separately, by keeping in state which ones are concerned.

```
function MagicList() {
    const [hidden, hiddenSet] = useState([]);
    const items = [{ id:1, text:'hello'}, { id:2, text:'from'}, { id:3, text:'the other sided'}]
    
    const hideMe = id => hiddenSet([...hidden, id]);

    return {
        items.filter( item => {
            return hidden.indexOf(item.id) !== -1;
        })
        .map( item => (
            <button key={item.id} onClick={hideMe.bind(this, item.id)}>{item.text}</button>
        ))
    };
}
```

**Edition**

`const hideMe = id => hiddenSet([...hidden, id]);`

It is just a fancy way to write:

```
    function hideMe(id) {
       const newArray = hidden.concat(id);
       hiddenSet(newArray);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you were trying to do there, so if by clicking the button, the button disappears then yes. however, because I'm new I'm not 100% sure how the hideMe function works.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a Set, Map, or object, to track the element ids you want hidden upon click of button. This provides `O(1)` lookups for what needs to be hidden. Be sure to render your *actual* text and not a string literal, i.e. `<p>{object.text}</p>` versus `<p>object.text</p>`.

```
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    hidden: {}, // <-- store ids to hide
    objects: [],
    search: "",
  };

  // Curried function to take id and return click handler function
  hideThisDiv = id => () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      hidden: {
        ...prevState.hidden, // <-- copy existing hidden state
        [id]: id // <-- add new id
      }
    }));
  }

  ...

  render() {
    const { hidden, objects } = this.state;

    return (
      <main>
        
        ...

        {objects
           .filter((el) => !hidden[el.uuid]) // <-- check id if not hidden
           .map(({ uuid, text }) => (
              <div key={uuid}>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={this.hideThisDiv(uuid)} // <-- attach handler
                >
                  Hide
                </button>
                <p>{text}</p>
              </div>
          ))}
      </main>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-hide-a-specific-element-inside-map-function-in-react]

Comment: Thank you for your response, it seems as if filtering this way won't work because the UUID can't be used as an index. In addition, the hideDiv function 'id' variable throws an implicitly no type error, any way to handle this?

Comment: @IN1994MAR Why would you use a guid as an index? Can you explain more what you mean? You probably don't want to associate an array index with anything being rendered as that can lead to UI updating issues when you are removing elements from the array being mapped. What is the error you are seeing with `hideThisDiv`? I don't see any such error in my running sandbox. Did you notice it is a curried function?

Comment: When running this line '!hidden[el.uuid])' i get an error the el.uuid cannot be used as input type, the error I'm seeing with HideThisDiv is that the first id when I declare the function throws a "Parameter "id" implicitly has an "any" type. what is a curried function?

Comment: @IN1994MAR Sounds like you are using typescript (or *some* typed flavor of JS). I don't know what the error about `el.uuid` can't be used as input type means in this vague context. For `hideThisDiv` the id type would be a string. [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) is a way to convert a function taking several arguments into a sequence of functions taking a single argument. The `onClick` callback receives an event object, currying allows us to write our handler in such a way as to not need an anonymous function to pass the argument we care about, the uuid.

Comment: Yes, indeed this is in typescript .. been working on this problem for hours....

Comment: @IN1994MAR Ok, I don't mean to shift the blame, but these are issues/errors with how you've typed your functions and parameters, the logic used in my solution is sound and is a common design pattern.